# Submit Infopath fields to different lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have an infopath form that submit repeating rows to a list in SP online, but there is one field that needs to submit to another list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can submit the rows of a repeating table in InfoPath from to a SharePoint list via submitting a CAML update batch to the UpdateListItems method of the Lists web service.

You can follow the steps in the article [How to submit the rows of a repeating table in InfoPath to a SharePoint list](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-submit-items-rows-repeating-table-infopath-sharepoint-list.htm)